# For loop with user input. The output starts with a space

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Apologies, I am starting out and can't work out what is going wrong here.

```
// Declare string to hold numbers output
        String lottoNum = "";

        // Declare scanner variable
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask user for numbers
        System.out.println("To buy a ticket we need your numbers...");

        // Set up loop for 6 numbers
        for (int i = 1; i<=6; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter lotto number " + i);
            String num = scan1.nextLine();
            lottoNum = lottoNum + ", " + num;
        }
        System.out.println(lottoNum);
```

It loops as intended, asking for lotto numbers 1 through 6. But at the end when it returns the lottoNum with a collection of all 6 numbers, it starts with a ", ".

```
Please enter lotto number 5
28
Please enter lotto number 6
19
, 22, 12, 4, 38, 28, 19
```

Why does it start off with this ", "? And can I prevent it from putting this at the beginning?

Comment: It starts of with that, because that is effectively the first thing you add - the initial value of `lottoNum` is an empty string, and then the first thing you do is assign the concatenation result of that empty string, followed by ", " and the first number.

Comment: Because the first time through, you add ", " to the empty string

Comment: When you for loop runs the first time, `lottoNum` is `""` and will therefore be set to `", 22"` by this line `lottoNum = lottoNum + ", " + num;`.

Comment: Perfect thanks all. I can see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add condition:

```
lottoNum = lottoNum + num;
if (i < 6) lottoNum = lottoNum + ", ";
```

It will add `,` at end of each number except the last number.

Comment: I think this is the easiest for me to understand with my present knowledge. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new string is not optimal. I'd suggest collecting all nums into a list and then use built-in String.join method.

And, of course, it's better to user scanner.nextInt() instead of scanner.nextLine() when parsing numbers.

```
    // Declare scanner variable
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Ask user for numbers
    System.out.println("To buy a ticket we need your numbers...");

    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // Set up loop for 6 numbers
    for (int i = 1; i<=6; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter lotto number " + i);
        nums.add(scan1.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(',', nums));
```

Comment: It may be too difficult for him now.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to save the first number before your for loop.

Then ask for the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you would like to use the StringJoiner class to get desired behaviour:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", "); //argument passed will separate passed objects
sj.add(String.valueOf(12));
sj.add(String.valueOf(24));
sj.add(String.valueOf(50));
System.out.println(sj);
```

The output:

```
12, 24, 50
```

You can use StringJoiner constructor with 3 parameters - you can use it to define prefix and suffix as well.